# Replace PHP variable with data from array

Tags: php, arrays, replace

So what I got is:
this array($errors) for example:

```
'F7000' => 'Undefined Fraud',
'V5000' => 'Undefined System',
'A0000' => 'Undefined Approved',
'V6110' => 'Invalid ProcessRequest Number',
.............etc lots more codes.
```

Now I am doing some code and in the end I get something like:

```
$message = $result->ResponseMessage = 'V6110';
```

Now, what I want to do, is show the user a more adequate message than V6110
How do I got to do it so that lets say I get something like

```
$message = 'Invalid ProcessRequest Number';
print $message;
```

That will show the user Invalid ProcessRequest Number ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All arrays in PHP are so called associative arrays, so you can use strings as array "indexes":

```
$error=array('F7000' => 'Undefined Fraud',
              'V5000' => 'Undefined System',
              'A0000' => 'Undefined Approved',
              'V6110' => 'Invalid ProcessRequest Number', '...so on');

$errorNo='V6110';    
$message = $error[$errorNo]; // will return you 'Invalid ProcessRequest Number'
if($message=='')
   $message = "Your Default Error Message";
print $message;
```

Comment: ok and possible to add an IF clause just in case the error mcode is not in my array to show another generic message ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$errors = array (
    'F7000' => 'Undefined Fraud',
    'V5000' => 'Undefined System',
    'A0000' => 'Undefined Approved',
    'V6110' => 'Invalid ProcessRequest Number',
    ...);
$message = 'V6110';
$message = $errors [$message];
echo $message;
```

Comment: Generally not a great idea to overwrite your error code with the error message - you should store the message in a separate var

Answer (score 0):

```
// show V6110 message
echo $errors['V6110'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$errorMsg= $errorArray[$result->ResponseMessage];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
$message = $errors[$result->ResponseMessage];
```